# Getting the exact layout of a Windows GUI

Tags: windows

Given a Windows process that has a GUI, I would like to be able to extract the exact layout and text that is presented in the GUI.
For example, if the Window looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to extract a nested representation of the controls that exist on the Window - the links (Workplace, Edit, Goto, Folder, etc), the title ('Business Workplace of...'), etc. I would love it to include the absolute positions, background colors, text, etc. The goal is to have the most **generic** way to extract it from any process.

Is there anything like that that exists somewhere? Anything similar or a direction?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal

Comment: Hey, thanks, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you read the overview document at that link?  It says "Both Microsoft Active Accessibility and UI Automation expose the UI object model as a hierarchical tree" which sounds exactly like what you are wanting.